# JavaFX Task Callable

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I was developing a JavaFX app and I was supplying the JavaFX tasks in an ExecutorService `submit` method. Also I was trying to get the return value of the `Task` in the return value of the submit in a `Future` object. Then I discovered that `ExecutorService` only returns value when you submit a `Callable` object, and JavaFX Tasks are runnables despite having a `call` method. so is there any workaround for this problem?

I tried and solved my problem this way but I'm open to suggestions when I don't want to write my own class.

My main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0,100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        List<Integer> sendingList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sendingList.add(iterator.next());
        }
        System.out.println("SUBMITTING");
        Future<Integer> future = executorService.submit((Callable<Integer>) new TestCallable(sendingList,semaphore));
        System.out.println(future.get());
        semaphore.acquire();
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    System.out.println("COMPLETED");
}
```

My `TestCallable` class:

```
class TestCallable extends Task<Integer> implements Callable<Integer> {

   private Random random = new Random();
   private List<Integer> list;
   private Semaphore semaphore;

   TestCallable(List<Integer> list, Semaphore semaphore) {
       this.list = list;
       this.semaphore = semaphore;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer call(){
       System.out.println("SENDING");
       System.out.println(list);
       try {
           Thread.sleep(1000+random.nextInt(500));
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       System.out.println("RECEIVED");
       semaphore.release();
       return list.size();
   }
}
```

Comment: You do notice that a) `Task` implements `Future` b) submitting the task and immediately calling `get` results in waiting in the calling thead waiting for the completion of the task. You just could have executed the task on the thread directly.

Comment: what if I have a multi-thread executor and I want to wait if there is no thread available, not for each task?

Comment: Calling `Future.get` you make sure to wait until the task is completed. Assuming the same priority for the submitting thread and the thread executing the task, running the task on a different thread is not faster and it does not result in any of the tasks from running in parallel even with a multi-threaded executor. Submitting a task in this scenario moves the work from one thread to another thread and keeps the submitting task busy waiting for the completion of the task...

Answer (score 1):

`Task` extends `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask` which in turn implements the `Future` interface. This means you can use a `Task` just like a `Future`.

```
Executor executor = ...;
Task<?> task = ...;
executor.execute(task);
task.get(); // Future method
```

This will cause the thread calling `get()` to wait until completion. However, a `Task`'s purpose is to communicate the progress of a background process with the JavaFX Application Thread. It's close relationship to the GUI means you will most likely be launching a `Task` from the FX thread. This will lead to `get()` being called on the FX thread which is not what you want as it will freeze the GUI until `get()` returns; you might as well have just called `Task.run` directly.

Instead, you should be using the asynchronous functionality provided by `Task`. If you want to retrieve the value when the `Task` completes successfully you can use the `onSucceeded` property or listen to the `value`/`state` property. There's also ways to listen for failure/cancellation.

```
Executor executor = ...;
Task<?> task = ...;
task.setOnSucceeded(event -> handleResult(task.getValue()));
task.setOnFailed(event -> handleException(task.getException()));
executor.execute(task);
```

If you don't need the functionality provided by `Task` then it would probably be best to simply use `Runnable` or `Callable` directly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you want to do here.

Firstly, your `Semaphore` does nothing because you used `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, which already guarantees that only one task can run at any point in time.

Secondly, like what @Slaw mentioned, you are potentially blocking on JavaFX Application thread, depending on your actual implementation (your example isn't really a JavaFX application).

Next, `ExecutorService` has 2 *main* overloads for `submit()`.

The first overload takes in a `Callable`. This overload allows you to retrieve the value returned by the `Callable` (by calling `get()` on the returned `Future`), because `Callable` refers to something that is *can be called* - it *can* return value.

The second overload takes in a `Runnable`. Since `Task` implements <del>`Future`</del> `RunnableFuture` interface, and <del>`Future`</del> `RunnableFuture` interface extends `Runnable` interface, passing in a `Task` would be equivalent to calling this overload. This overload does not expect a result to be returned, because `Runnable` is something that you run without a result. Calling `get()` on the `Future` returned by this overload will block until the task finishes, and `null` will be returned. If you need to retrieve the value returned by the `Task`, you need to call `get()` of the `Task`, not the `Future` returned by `ExecutorService.submit()`.

#### Edit based on OP's comments

Firstly, since the calling method is already running in a background thread, and all tasks are expected to run sequentially (instead of parallelly), then you should just run them without all these additional `ExecutorService` and `Task`, unless there is another reason why this has to be done.

Secondly, a `List` object is nothing but an object doing referencing. What could have really affected performance is that you are copying the reference of the elements to the new list. You could have used [List.subList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int))if the indices are known, as the returned list would use the same backing array as the original list, so there isn't an additional `O(n)` operation for copying.

Comment: my semaphore is there to make sure I create each sublist just before I'm ready to run a new thread. in my actual application the list is much bigger and submitting them would take a lot of memory and choke the CPU.

Comment: Also in my application I run the executor on another background daemon thread, so it won't freeze my GUI. This is just a test code.

Comment: "_Since `Task` implements `Future` interface, and `Future` interface extends `Runnable` interface..._". `Future` does not extend `Runnable`. I believe you're thinking of `RunnableFuture` (which `Task` does implement through extending `FutureTask`).